# Basic HTTP authentication in Node.JS?

Tags: http, authentication, node.js, basic-authentication

I'm trying to write a REST-API server with NodeJS like the one used by [Joyent](http://api.no.de), and everything is ok except I can't verify a normal user's authentication. If I jump to a terminal and do `curl -u username:password localhost:8000 -X GET`, I can't get the values username:password on the NodeJS http server. If my NodeJS http server is something like

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

, shouldn't I get the values username:password somewhere in the **req** object that comes from the callback ?
How can I get those values without having to use [Connect's basic http auth](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-basicAuth.html) ?

Comment: console.dir(req.headers)

Comment: console.dir(req.headers) only outputs { authorization: 'Basic am9hb2plcm9uaW1vOmJsYWJsYWJsYQ==',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18',
  host: 'localhost:8000',
  accept: '*/*' }

Comment: for Express 4 see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616371/basic-http-authentication-with-node-and-express-4)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The username:password is contained in the Authorization header *as a base64-encoded string*.

Try this:

```
const http = require('http');
 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var header = req.headers.authorization || '';       // get the auth header
  var token = header.split(/\s+/).pop() || '';        // and the encoded auth token
  var auth = Buffer.from(token, 'base64').toString(); // convert from base64
  var parts = auth.split(/:/);                        // split on colon
  var username = parts.shift();                       // username is first
  var password = parts.join(':');                     // everything else is the password
 
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('username is "' + username + '" and password is "' + password + '"');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

From [HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication - Part 2 Basic Authentication Scheme (Pages 4-5)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

*Basic Authentication in Backus-Naur Form*

```
basic-credentials = base64-user-pass
base64-user-pass  = <base64 [4] encoding of user-pass,
                    except not limited to 76 char/line>
user-pass   = userid ":" password
userid      = *<TEXT excluding ":">
password    = *TEXT
```

Comment: Don't forget to parse out the "Basic", 
i.e.:
'Basic abcdef0123456789' === req.headers.authorization

Comment: The third line in the example already does this by splitting the header on whitespace to produce ["Basic","abcdef0123456789"] and popping off the last value, which will be the authorization token.

Comment: It's much better to use the express.basicAuth method instead to handle all the issues. Simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Agree, but the OP didn't wish to do so.

Comment: This may fail, if the password contains a colon.

Answer (score 38):

If you're using express, you can use the connect plugin (included with express):

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');

//User validation
var auth = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {     
   return (user == "super" && pass == "secret");
},'Super duper secret area');

//Password protected area
app.get('/admin', auth, routes.admin);
```

Comment: I don't believe this works any longer from Express 4 onwards. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283848/express-basicauth-throwing-error?answertab=votes#tab-top or use something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-auth as an alternative

Comment: Yes http-auth should just do fine.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [node-http-digest](https://github.com/kaero/node-http-digest) for basic auth or [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth), if adding authorization from external services are in you roadmap.

Answer (score 6):

I use this code for my own starter sites with auth.

It does several things:

- basic auth
- return index.html for / route
- serve content without crashing and silent handle the error
- allow port parameter when running
- minimal amount of logging

Before using the code, npm install express

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//User validation
var auth = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {     
     return (user == "username" && pass == "password") ? true : false;
},'dev area');

/* serves main page */
app.get("/", auth, function(req, res) {
try{
    res.sendfile('index.html')
}catch(e){}
});

/* add your other paths here */

/* serves all the static files */
app.get(/^(.+)$/, auth, function(req, res){ 
try{
    console.log('static file request : ' + req.params);
    res.sendfile( __dirname + req.params[0]); 
}catch(e){}
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be implemented easily in pure node.js with no dependency, this is my version which is based on [this answer for express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616372/1414809) but simplified so you can see the basic idea easily:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    const userpass = Buffer.from(
        (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '',
        'base64'
    ).toString();
    if (userpass !== 'username:password') {
        res.writeHead(401, { 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="nope"' });
        res.end('HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized: Access is denied');
        return;
    }
    res.end('You are in! Yay!!');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 3):

The restify framework (http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/) includes an authorization header parser for "basic" and "signature" authentication schemes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth) module

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```