# user- session management nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, client-server, restful-authentication, express

I have been trying to get my head around nodeJS and expressJS, and I found some really good [examples](http://chat.nodejs.org/).

I could understand chat in nodeJS to, but I could not figure out 
[1](https://github.com/Marak/session.js/blob/master/README.md) or [2](https://github.com/akdubya/rbytes) modules.

Is there a really good example that explains how to do it?

This is the first time I am working with it.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? session management or chat app?

Comment: SESSSION MANAGEMENT. I am sorry, it was a lil too confusing.

Comment: did you take a look at this example on the expressjs guide page? http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support

Comment: Yes, I did have a look at that.. Is there a possibility to do it anyother way, other than using cookies? probably using uuid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic HTTP authentication in Node.JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951552/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js)