# Nodejitsu: is there a way to password protect the apps?

Tags: javascript, authentication, http-authentication, nodejitsu

using Nodejitsu: is there a way to password protect the apps?
i'm not sure if i can deploy an .htaccess or so... i just need to protect the site from accidental visitors

thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951552/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js

Comment: thanks! sounds the exact topic i was looking for...i'm newbie in nodeJs didn't know was possible!

Comment: @GeorgeP Turn your comment into an answer so this can be marked as answered, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load express
var express = require('express');

//User validation
  var auth = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {     
   return (user == "super" && pass == "secret");
  },'Super duper secret area');

 //Password protected area
 app.get('/admin', auth, routes.admin);
```