# HTTP Simple Authentication vs POST Form Authentication

Tags: web-services, node.js, web-applications

i'm reading [RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) and on the first chapters they talk about taking advantages over the stuff HTTP already serves.

They introduce en example that does authentication to `del.icio.us` using `HTTP Basic Authentication`.

Until now, the apps I've been written in NodeJS implemeted Authentication by sending a `POST` request from a form containing `user` and a `password` field.

How do you guys implement this? Do webpages implement auth via `http basic auth`?
Which one is recommended?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: form login usually means there's a cookie involved. but http auth works just as well, at the cost of transmitting the user/pass in almost-cleartext on every request.

Comment: so form-based authentication should be used in user-end Web Applications to preserve the user logged in, and Web Services being accesed from webapps could implement http-simple-auth?

Answer (score 1):

You may find [Basic HTTP authentication in Node.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951552/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js/5957629#5957629) useful as it describes how to do Basic Authentication in NodeJS.

As for its use in Web Services, well...there are lots of ways to authorize requests from using a shared secret (like an API key), cookies (like Basic Auth) or user credentials added to a request string. All have their pluses and minuses.

For most of my coding, I rely on public/private key pairs to assure the identity of clients.

Answer (score 0):

[http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module should do the job

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```