# Make a NodeJs application private on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, basic-authentication

I'm trying to make a NodeJS application on Heroku private so that only developers can see it. Is there a simply way to do that, like basic auth? (All of the solutions I keep finding are specific to Ruby apps).

Comment: Are you using any sort of framework?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to leverage basic authentication, here are two options: [http-auth](https://npmjs.org/package/http-auth) and [Passport](http://passportjs.org/). http-auth is a very simple module and Passport is a powerful module with alternatives for authentication. Both modules provide code examples ranging from basic code to Express framework integration.

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is asking for. This answers how to authenticate a user on an app. Not how to secure a stain environment, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I managed to get one solution working that may work for you but wasn't suitable for me as it seems to interfere with the built in user login from angular-fullstack.

I just wanted a quick way to password protect the app so that only developers and stakeholders could see it. https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-auth seems to do the trick.

This involves add http-auth to your project (npm install http-auth --save). Then you'll need to find the file where your createServer is defined and the code there.

If you're using Express you can do something like this

```
// HTTP Authentication 
var preAuth = require('http-auth');
var basic = preAuth.basic({
        realm: "Restricted Access! Please login to proceed"
    }, function (username, password, callback) { 
         callback( (username === "user" && password === "password"));
    }
);

// Setup server
var app = express();
    app.use(preAuth.connect(basic));
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
```

If not then you can try one of the options from the http-auth documentation e.g.

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
        realm: "Simon Area."
    }, function (username, password, callback) { // Custom authentication method.
        callback(username === "Tina" && password === "Bullock");
    }
);

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```

Here are also a couple of related threads with somewhat similar approaches.

[express.basicAuth throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283848/express-basicauth-throwing-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[Basic HTTP authentication in Node.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951552/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js)