# how to implement curl u option in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, curl

I am trying to implement a curl request in node. In curl you can perform the following POST request:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "client_id:client_secret" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I understand how to set headers and write the data payload using the node `http` module, but how do i implement `-u client_id:client_secret` using the `http` module?

Comment: I think this answer describes the process from the server side. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957629/2966874

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I do not know nodejs. But as you know how to set the Headers `-H` from nodejs, I believe I can help you now! `-u client_id:client_secret` is equivalent to the following one:

```
-H "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Here `XXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the base64 of the string `client_id:client_secret`. Don't forget the `:` at the middle of them.

Answer (score 0):

`curl -u` base64 encodes the `"username:password"` string and appends the result as a header.

In nodejs, it's as simple as adding `auth` field to http.request's options.

```js
const req = http.request({
  hostname: "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
  path: "/v1/oauth2/token",
  auth: "client_id:client_secret",
  // ...
```

Behind the scenes, node is base64 encoding the string and adding a formatted header. If you're using another http client, it may also be helpful to know how to manually add the header.

1. base64 encode your `"username:password"` with the [Buffer module](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html):

```js
const credentials = Buffer.from("client_id:client_secret").toString("base64");
```

2. Add the base64 encoded string as a header in the following format:

```js
const req = http.request({
  hostname: "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
  path: "/v1/oauth2/token",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`
  // ...
```