# Basic HTTP authentication with Node and Express 4

Tags: node.js, http, express, http-authentication

It looks like implementing basic HTTP authentication with Express v3 was trivial:

```
app.use(express.basicAuth('username', 'password'));
```

Version 4 (I'm using 4.2) removed the `basicAuth` middleware, though, so I'm a little stuck. I have the following code, but it doesn't cause the browser to prompt the user for credentials, which is what I'd like (and what I imagine the old method did):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var user = auth(req);

    if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== 'username' || user['pass'] !== 'password') {
        res.writeHead(401, 'Access invalid for user', {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Invalid credentials');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Shameless plug: I maintain a fairly popular module that makes that easy and has most standard features you would need: [express-basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth)

Comment: I recently forked @LionC 's package because I had to adapt it (enabling context-aware authorizers) in a ultra-short span of time for a company project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/spresso-authy

Comment: @LionC it is unclear from docs of `express-basic-auth` how to apply it to just one route.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I used the code for the original [`basicAuth`](https://github.com/expressjs/basic-auth-connect/blob/master/index.js) to find the answer:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var user = auth(req);

    if (user === undefined || user['name'] !== 'username' || user['pass'] !== 'password') {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="MyRealmName"');
        res.end('Unauthorized');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: this module is considered deprecated, use [jshttp/basic-auth](https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth) instead (same api so answer still applies)

Answer (score 197):

## Simple Basic Auth with vanilla JavaScript *(ES6)*

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // authentication middleware

  const auth = {login: 'yourlogin', password: 'yourpassword'} // change this

  // parse login and password from headers
  const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || ''
  const [login, password] = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString().split(':')

  // Verify login and password are set and correct
  if (login && password && login === auth.login && password === auth.password) {
    // Access granted...
    return next()
  }

  // Access denied...
  res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="401"') // change this
  res.status(401).send('Authentication required.') // custom message

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

})
```

<sub>*note: This "middleware" can be used in any handler. Just remove `next()` and reverse the logic.  See the **1-statement** example below, or the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33905671/revisions) of this answer.*</sub>

#### Why?

- `req.headers.authorization` contains the value "`Basic <base64 string>`", but it can also be empty and we don't want it to fail, hence the weird combo of `|| ''`
- Node doesn't know `atob()` and `btoa()`, hence the [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)

#### ES6 -> ES5

[`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is just `var` .. sort of
[`(x, y) => {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is just `function(x, y) {...}`
[`const [login, password] = ...split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is just two `var` assignments in one

[source of inspiration (uses packages)](https://davidbeath.com/posts/expressjs-40-basicauth.html)

---

The above is a **super simple** example that was intended to be **super short** and quickly deployable to your playground server. But as was pointed out in the comments, passwords can also contain colon characters `:`. To correctly extract it from the *b64auth*, you can use this.

```
  // parse login and password from headers
  const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || ''
  const strauth = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString()
  const splitIndex = strauth.indexOf(':')
  const login = strauth.substring(0, splitIndex)
  const password = strauth.substring(splitIndex + 1)

  // using shorter regex by @adabru
  // const [_, login, password] = strauth.match(/(.*?):(.*)/) || []
```

## Basic auth in one statement

...on the other hand, if you only ever use one or very few logins, this is the bare minimum you need: *(you don't even need to parse the credentials at all)*

```
function (req, res) {
//btoa('yourlogin:yourpassword') -> "eW91cmxvZ2luOnlvdXJwYXNzd29yZA=="
//btoa('otherlogin:otherpassword') -> "b3RoZXJsb2dpbjpvdGhlcnBhc3N3b3Jk"

  // Verify credentials
  if (  req.headers.authorization !== 'Basic eW91cmxvZ2luOnlvdXJwYXNzd29yZA=='
     && req.headers.authorization !== 'Basic b3RoZXJsb2dpbjpvdGhlcnBhc3N3b3Jk')        
    return res.status(401).send('Authentication required.') // Access denied.   

  // Access granted...
  res.send('hello world')
  // or call next() if you use it as middleware (as snippet #1)
}
```

---

PS: do you need to have both "secure" and "public" paths? Consider using [`express.router`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) instead.

```
var securedRoutes = require('express').Router()

securedRoutes.use(/* auth-middleware from above */)
securedRoutes.get('path1', /* ... */) 

app.use('/secure', securedRoutes)
app.get('public', /* ... */)

// example.com/public       // no-auth
// example.com/secure/path1 // requires auth
```

Comment: Don't use `.split(':')` because it will choke on passwords containing at least one colon. Such passwords are valid according to [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt).

Comment: You can also use RegExp `const [_, login, password] = strauth.match(/(.*?):(.*)/) || []` for the colon part.

Comment: Using `!==` to compare passwords leaves you vulnerable to timing attacks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack make sure you use a constant time string compare.

Comment: Use `Buffer.from() // for strings` or `Buffer.alloc() // for numbers` as `Buffer()` is deprecated due to security issues.

Comment: Downvoted because of the timing attack vulnerability. This should use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_timingsafeequal_a_b instead. See for example how express-basic-auth implemented this, https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth/blob/fa600c90707a69f1f3a0fa9f0295f412fc207e4e/index.js#L5-L17.

Comment: @ThibaudColas Can you please link to an article for others to see, explaining why this is an issue on a remote http server, where among other aspects, for example, the response time introduces a non-deterministic time delay, which in my laic opinion obfuscates this vulnerability?

Comment: @Qwerty I don’t have a good single article on the topic (does Wikipedia help? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack shared by @hraban). Your opinion is on point – network factors make timing attacks less practical. But relying on this would be a case of "security through obscurity" – it might help here and there, but it’s not as good of a protection as implementing constant-time comparison. See https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-7576 for a similar vulnerability in Rails, and how its severity is rated.

Comment: A _timing attack_ here means _figuring out the password by measuring how long the string comparison takes_. `"0123456789" === "??????????"` would fail slightly quicker than `"0123456789" === "012345678?"` because the numbers of characters that need to be compared to tell the equalities (1 and 10 respectively) are different.

Comment: I learned a lot reading through this.

Answer (score 132):

## TL;DR:

#### ☒ `express.basicAuth` is gone
☒ `basic-auth-connect` is deprecated
☒ `basic-auth` doesn't have any logic
☒ `http-auth` is an overkill
☑ `express-basic-auth` is what you want

### More info:

Since you're using Express then you can use the `express-basic-auth` middleware.

See the docs:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth

Example:

```
const app = require('express')();
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
 
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { admin: 'supersecret123' },
    challenge: true // <--- needed to actually show the login dialog!
}));
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out about `challenge: true` option

Comment: @VitaliiZurian Good point - I added it to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rsp Do you know how to apply this only to specific routes?

Comment: If you don't want to add other dependencies, it's very easy to write basic auth by hand on one line...

Comment: how would the client url look like ?

Comment: This answer was the solution to the problem I was looking for, however it strangely changed the behavior of static files, which now have precedence over routes, I had to delete index.html for this to work for some reason. Node is weird!

Comment: How safe would this be to protect my Heroku app that I have deployed for personal usage? I have in the past been a victim of having my AWS keys stolen and used so I am asking here as a precaution since my personal app contains sensitive info.

Comment: Best answer imo. Fast and helpful

Comment: Qwerty's comment and answer above are great as exercises. However, there are very few scenarios where rolling your own authentication strategy for a real, publicly available application is a good idea; there's too much room for error. The _vast majority_ of users are better off using a well documented, widely deployed solution like express-basic-auth.

Comment: Any idea of how to replace that dialog from the challenge for a proper login.html page ?

Answer (score 59):

A lot of the middleware was pulled out of the Express core in v4, and put into separate modules.  The basic auth module is here: https://github.com/expressjs/basic-auth-connect

Your example would just need to change to this:

```
var basicAuth = require('basic-auth-connect');
app.use(basicAuth('username', 'password'));
```

Comment: This module claims to be deprecated (though the alternative it suggests seems unsatisfying)

Comment: ^^ absolutely unsatisfying as in densely undocumented. zero example of use as middleware, which it's probably good for, but the invocation is unavailable.  the example they give is great for generality, but not for usage info.

Comment: Yeah this one is deprecated, and while the one recommended is low on docs, the code is very simple https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I've described how to use the `basic-auth` library in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46981895/1470897)

Comment: How does an entire module exist based around *putting the password in clear text in the code*?? At least obscuring it by comparing in base64 seems marginally better.

Answer (score 34):

I changed in express 4.0 the basic authentication with [http-auth](https://github.com/gevorg/http-auth), the code is:

```
var auth = require('http-auth');

var basic = auth.basic({
        realm: "Web."
    }, function (username, password, callback) { // Custom authentication method.
        callback(username === "userName" && password === "password");
    }
);

app.get('/the_url', auth.connect(basic), routes.theRoute);
```

Comment: This is literally plug and play. Exellent.

Answer (score 21):

There seems to be multiple modules to do that, some are deprecated.

This one looks active:
https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth

Here's a use example:

```
// auth.js

var auth = require('basic-auth');

var admins = {
  'art@vandelay-ind.org': { password: 'pa$$w0rd!' },
};


module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  var user = auth(req);
  if (!user || !admins[user.name] || admins[user.name].password !== user.pass) {
    res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"');
    return res.status(401).send();
  }
  return next();
};




// app.js

var auth = require('./auth');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// ... some not authenticated middlewares

app.use(auth);

// ... some authenticated middlewares
```

Make sure you put the `auth` middleware in the correct place, any middleware before that will not be authenticated.

Comment: I am actually in favor of 'basic-auth-connect', name is bad but functionality wise it it is better than 'basic-auth'. All the latter does, is parse authorization header. You still have to `implement` the protocol yourself (aka send correct header)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for this. This worked and explained everything nicely.

Comment: I tried this, but it just keeps asking me to login via continous loop.

Answer (score 7):

We can implement the basic authorization without needing any module

```
//1.
var http = require('http');

//2.
var credentials = {
    userName: "vikas kohli",
    password: "vikas123"
};
var realm = 'Basic Authentication';

//3.
function authenticationStatus(resp) {
    resp.writeHead(401, { 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="' + realm + '"' });
    resp.end('Authorization is needed');

};

//4.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var authentication, loginInfo;

    //5.
    if (!request.headers.authorization) {
        authenticationStatus (response);
        return;
    }

    //6.
    authentication = request.headers.authorization.replace(/^Basic/, '');

    //7.
    authentication = (new Buffer(authentication, 'base64')).toString('utf8');

    //8.
    loginInfo = authentication.split(':');

    //9.
    if (loginInfo[0] === credentials.userName && loginInfo[1] === credentials.password) {
        response.end('Great You are Authenticated...');
         // now you call url by commenting the above line and pass the next() function
    }else{

    authenticationStatus (response);

}

});
 server.listen(5050);
```

Source:- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1231/basic-authentication-using-nodejs

Answer (score 7):

```
function auth (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
      var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
      res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
      err.status = 401;
      next(err);
      return;
  }
  var auth = new Buffer.from(authHeader.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString().split(':');
  var user = auth[0];
  var pass = auth[1];
  if (user == 'admin' && pass == 'password') {
      next(); // authorized
  } else {
      var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
      res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');      
      err.status = 401;
      next(err);
  }
}
app.use(auth);
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 7):

install the express-basic-auth dependency:

```
 npm i express-basic-auth
```

Require the auth package where you create your app

```
const app = require('express')();
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
```

and setup the middleware like this:

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'my-username': 'my-password' },
    challenge: true,
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Express has removed this functionality and now recommends you use the [basic-auth](https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth) library.

Here's an example of how to use:

```
var http = require('http')
var auth = require('basic-auth')

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var credentials = auth(req)

  if (!credentials || credentials.name !== 'aladdin' || credentials.pass !== 'opensesame') {
    res.statusCode = 401
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"')
    res.end('Access denied')
  } else {
    res.end('Access granted')
  }
})

// Listen
server.listen(3000)
```

To send a request to this route you need to include an [Authorization header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) formatted for basic auth.

Sending a curl request first you must take the [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) encoding of `name:pass` or in this case `aladdin:opensesame` which is equal to `YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l`

Your curl request will then look like:

```
 curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l" http://localhost:3000/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, i know, but i don't like any of these...and this is what i use. So i'm kind of putting it here so next time i'm looking for it i can find a solution i like.

This requires no modules and even works all the way back to node 9.

```
 ...
 myRoute: function(req, res, next) {
  
  // first and foremost...send the request to authenticate
  const reject = () => {
    res.setHeader("www-authenticate", "Basic");
    res.sendStatus(401);
  };
  
  // next check and see if they have tried to authenticate
  const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  
  if (!authorization) {
    // okay, well send the request for authentication here
    return reject();
  }
  
  // break open the authorization object sent by the users
  const [username, password] = Buffer.from(
    authorization.replace("Basic ", ""), "base64"
  ).toString().split(":");
  
  // do NOT leave here!! pull them in from .env or secrets
  if (!(username === "user" && password === "p@ssw0rb")) {
    return reject();
  }
  
  // okay now put your regularly scheduled route result in
  res.send('you\'re in myRoute!');
},
...
```