# How do I password protect a subdirectory of a Harp.js app

Tags: node.js, authentication, harp

How do I password protect a subdirectory in a Harp site (running under Node)?

I want something like [basic auth](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/basicauth) but for a single folder, not the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Harp through command line, by running `harp server` then you can't because then it's just a static file server and you can't do any server-side coding.

You'll have to switch to Express ([here's how to use BasicAuth with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616371/basic-http-authentication-with-node-and-express-4)). 
You can still use Harp (as a static server, like you were using it before) from within Express ([as a middleware](http://harpjs.com/docs/environment/lib)). Or you can just use [Express static](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html)