# How to check if user is authorized? (basic-auth)

Tags: node.js

I'm using `var basicAuth  = require('basic-auth');` and I need to check if the user is authorized.

```
var basicAuth  = require('basic-auth');
module.exports.authorize = function authorize(req, res, next) {
    var authInfo = basicAuth(req);
    bluebird.resolve().then(() => {
        if (!authInfo) { // Authorization header is not provided, send forbidden.
          throw new Error('Invalid username and/or password.');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit to include a question as I'm not totally clear on what you're asking...?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter, How to check if user is authorized? i am sure i typed properly hmm

Comment: @AxOn And if user is not authorized - what should happened?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski, else no matter, just some console.log

Comment: @AxOn change line where error is thrown to console.log and for the future some documentation can help you - https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth

Comment: Does this other SO answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27729601/1095011