# Configure Basic HTTP Authentication with Google App Engine Node.js App

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

I'm running a GAE Standard Env. node/express app.

How can I configure Basic HTTP Authentication?

**Is it possible to configure it with `app.yaml`?**

I've read the docs, and did a lot of searching and so far it seems like I'll have to use my Express server to handle it. That seems weird because it requires that I have a server.

What if I wanted to serve a static HTML page? Then the express solution falls apart.

In `nginx` I can do this:

```
server {
    ...
    auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
}
```

Is there an equivalent with `app.yaml` in GAE?

Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not possible to do this type of authentication, but you have other [options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/authenticating-users)
- google sign in
- oauth
- firebase
* users api is available but not for node standard app engine

If you wanted to serve static html you might store it in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/use-cases/) and Cloud storage has its own permissions [options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists)

Comment: Hey Andres, appreciate the response. I pretty much came to the same conclusion. It's kind of a pain, but I understand that Google's Authentication options are a bit more robust.

I am currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth. As referenced in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616371/basic-http-authentication-with-node-and-express-4

Comment: I accepted this as the answer for now. It's pretty annoying that you can't configure something so...basic ;) However, you CAN use Google IAP - https://cloud.google.com/iap/

Comment: @Mk-Etlinger I'm pretty sure you'd be able to do it by just sending the correct headers and files yourself in your app. I.E., *don't* make the authentication-required files static, and instead have them redirect to your script that handles HTTP Authentication. Example for PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php