# How is -u of curl request is accessed in node js request message?

Tags: node.js, express, curl

I have curl request as below,

```
curl -u user:password http://localhost:3000/user
```

How do I access the user and password passed in the http request on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `-u` specifies the username and password for the [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#basic_authentication_scheme).

It is accessible via the Request-Header `Authorization` (`req.headers.authorization`), but is encoded with `base64`.

The below code will read the header and decode the string, and then store the `username` and the `password` in seperate variables.

```
const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || ''
const strauth = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString()
const splitIndex = strauth.indexOf(':')
const login = strauth.substring(0, splitIndex)
const password = strauth.substring(splitIndex + 1)
```

For more information see [Basic HTTP authentication with Node and Express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616371/basic-http-authentication-with-node-and-express-4)